# Converting Double to String with desired decimal separator

Tags: vb.net

I have to convert number (double) to string like this:

```
Dim myDouble = 3.14
Dim myDoubleStr = myDouble.ToString ''OR myDouble.ToString("N")
```

According to my 'culture' settings result is "3,14" what is in most cases OK.
But here are cases that I need string representation of a number with decimal point instead of comma.
In that case I replace char "," with "." like string manipulation.

Is here a way that "ToString" convert a number with decimal point directly when this is needed?

Comment: Application.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator

Comment: I don't want to change NumberDecimalSeparator for whole application. Just for some conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

More info here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString

Answer (score 2):

You can also have as much precession as you want by specifying the format like this:

```
Dim myDouble As Double = 3.14159268
Dim myDoubleStr = myDouble.ToString("0.00000")  'The value will be 3.14159
```

In case you wanted to use Thousands separator, use this format:

```
Dim myDouble = 961327.1234567890
Dim MyDoubleStr = myDouble.ToString("#,##0.00000")
      'The value of MyDoubleStr will be 961,327.12345
```

Comment: Note: It will highlight `myDouble` and I get an error of "Invalid qualifier" using both ways using this in VBA.